# Does this query include a correlated or non correlated subquery?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

So I've written a simple query that gives me the ID #s for properties that show up only once in the property_usage table, along with the code for their associated usage type. Since I didn't want to include a column that shows the count of how many times each property ID shows up in the property_usage table, I wrote two subqueries to get a list of all the property IDs that only show up once. I then use the result of those subqueries (a single column of propertyIDs) to filter out those properties that show up more than once in the table.

here's the query:

```
select pu.property_id, pu.usage_type_id 
from acres_final_40.property_usage pu
where pu.property_id not in 
  (select multiple_use_properties 
  from 
    (select pu.property_id multiple_use_properties, count(pu.property_id) 
    from acres_final_40.property_usage pu
    group by pu.property_id having count(pu.property_id) > 1))
order by pu.property_id;
```

My question is: is that innermost subquery correlated or noncorrelated with the outermost query?

I have the following thoughts (see the paragraph below), but I'd like to know for sure whether I'm right about this. I'm learning all this stuff on my own and don't have anyone I can ask about this in person!

My feeling is that it's not, because it seems like the pu.propertyID column from the outermost query isn't a value that's passed into the innermost query. It seems like the innermost query may technically be a derived table, in which case my code is sloppy because I don't alias the table name in the FROM clause of that SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In a SQL database query, a correlated subquery (also known as a synchronized subquery) is a subquery (a query nested inside another query) that *uses values from the outer query*.

([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery), emph. mine.)

Yours does not, so it's not a correlated subquery. Basically, if you can cut away the subquery and run it as an independent query, without the outer context, it's definitely uncorrelated. It can be done in your case.

BTW you could probably rewrite it using a `not exists` clause to check if another record with the same PK but another `property_id` exists, and get a better query plan than using `count()`. This is my speculation, though; only an `explain plan` would show if there's a benefit.